# jquery mobile listview ignores parent div css rules

Tags: jquery, css, listview, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to put a jquery mobile listview within a parent div but the listview ignores any parent css rules.

```
<div data-role="page" id="profile">
    <div data-role="content">
     <div class="content_white">
        <ul data-role="listview" data-theme="c"  class="custom-list">
            <li>test</li>
            <li>one</li>
        </ul>
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

the parent div has the following css rules

```
.content_white{
position:relative;
margin-bottom:5% !important;
background-color:#ffffff;
border:1px solid #cccccc;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
border-radius: 5px;
```

}

basically I want the listview to nest inside the parent div

[JS fiddle answer](http://jsfiddle.net/e9Anb/4/)

Answer (score 0):

Centering the margins on the list seemed to do the trick

```
.custom-list{
margin: 0 auto !important;
padding-bottom:1%;
 }
```